# Php Mail not send from my server

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have code for enquiry form with mail send. It is working fine while I'm using gmail account, but when I'm using my own server mail it didn't sent. Below is my code.

```
if($register)
{
    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: <no-reply@xyz.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: check@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Bcc: checknew@xyx.com' . "\r\n";
    mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: which server is there? godaddy?

Comment: Did you check in SPAM folder? Also contact the support and ask them what is the issue. Usually we use `SMTP PHP class` in order to send emails.

Comment: i have check this code it is working fine you should check in your spam folder also

Comment: yes i did but i din't get anything.. Can i need to do any settings in server side..?

Comment: When you use the `mail()` function, it sends using a local mail server, so check your mail server logs, probably somewhere like `/var/log/mail.log`. Please don't tag your questions with PHPMailer when you're not using PHPMailer.

Comment: does your server have an SMTP server installed? :)